# Where in Azure portal can i check Requests/sec, Ingress GB/sec and Egress GB/sec for my Azure cloud services?

Tags: azure, networking, monitoring, usage-statistics, azure-resource-manager

I need to get  statistics for my Azure cloud services:
Requests/sec,
Ingress GB/sec,
Egress GB/sec . Where can I find these on Azure (ASM/ARM) Portal ?

Comment: Check Azure Application Insights: https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/

Comment: If third party products are an option, check out CloudMonix @ http://www.cloudmonix.com -- ton of metrics and automation for Cloud Services

Answer (score 0):

> I need to get statistics for my Azure cloud services: Requests/sec, Ingress GB/sec, Egress GB/sec . Where can I find these on Azure (ASM/ARM) Portal ?

On [Azure classic portal](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/cloud-services/cloud-services-how-to-monitor) and new portal, we could find that currently it enables us to check only these metrics (CPU percentage, Disk read/write, Network In/Out).

On Azure classic portal

[image]

On new portal

[image]

For monitoring incoming requests, you could try to use [Live Metrics Stream](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/application-insights/app-insights-live-stream).